# Pandas replace values if value isin dictionary of key and values as list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I do realize this has already been addressed here (e.g., [pandas: replace column value with keys and values in a dictionary of list values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72185441/14045537), [Replace column values by dictionary keys if they are in dictionary values (list)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46432315/14045537)). Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

I want to replace values in the `dataframe` `COl` with `key` if the column value is present in the `list values` of the `dictionary`

**Sample dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ["Apple", "Appy", "aple","Banana", "Banaa", "Banananan", "Carrot", "Mango", "Pineapple"]})
```

```
remap_dict = {"Apple": ["Appy", "aple"],
              "Banana": ["Banaa", "Banananan"]}
```

pandas `replace` doesn't support dictionary with key value(list):

```
df["Col"].replace(remap_dict, regex=True)
```

Is there a way to replace values in the `pandas` dataframe with keys in the `dictionary` if the value is in the list??

**Desired Output:**

```
     Col
0   Apple
1   Apple
2   Apple
3   Banana
4   Banana
5   Banana
6   Carrot
7   Mango
8   Pineapple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with flatten lists first:

```
d1 = {x: k for k, v in remap_dict.items() for x in v}
print (d1)
{'Appy': 'Apple', 'aple': 'Apple', 'Banaa': 'Banana', 'Banananan': 'Banana'}
```

And then use `replace` or mapping by `map`:

```
s = df["Col"].replace(d1)
```

---

```
s = df["Col"].map(d1).fillna(df['Col'])

print (s)
0        Apple
1        Apple
2        Apple
3       Banana
4       Banana
5       Banana
6       Carrot
7        Mango
8    Pineapple
Name: Col, dtype: object
```